# jquery dropdown, content in neighbour

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Usually, when you enter the menu, you are allowed to browse menu items. In this code it is not working:

http://jsfiddle.net/petrm/xwtS5/

Is it because the items are not inside menu element? If so, could it be solved in jQuery, instead of moving the code?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, use something like the [Superfish plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/), it does everything for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works well with [Superfish plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)